# MediaElement.js + jQuery with improved playlist (hopefully)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mediaelement.js, playlist

My JavaScript framework: jQuery 1.8.3

Using mediaelement.js and playlist to play audio (from this thread)
[mediaelement.js and custom playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867779/mediaelement-js-and-custom-playlist)

I've been trying to figure out how to change the script (at bottom) to use this kind of list:

```
 <ul class="mejs-list">
     <li class="current"><a href="/media/file-1.mp3">Nice Name for file1</a> 
       other random text or html/img, file description etc </li>
    <li><a href="/media/file-2.mp3">Nice Name for file2</a>other text or html/img</li>
    <li><a href="/media/file-3.mp3">Nice Name for file3</a>other text or html/img</li>
</ul>
```

instead of this one

```
<ul class="mejs-list">
  <li>/media/file-1.mp3</li>
  <li class="current">/media/file-2.mp3</li>
  <li>/media/file-3.mp3</li>
</ul>
```

This script turns this list into a playlist, and works very well, but creates links displaying full path, I prefer to grab the src from the link instead of just the text inside the li, so I can use better names.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
                mejsPlayNext(e.target);
            }, false);
        },
        keyActions: []
    });

    $('.mejs-list li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
        var audio_src = $(this).text();
        $('audio#mejs:first').each(function(){
            this.player.pause();
            this.player.setSrc(audio_src);
            this.player.play();
        });
    });

});

function mejsPlayNext(currentPlayer) {
    if ($('.mejs-list li.current').length > 0){ // get the .current song
        var current_item = $('.mejs-list li.current:first'); // :first is added if we have few .current classes
        var audio_src = $(current_item).next().text();
        $(current_item).next().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
        console.log('if '+audio_src);
    }else{ // if there is no .current class
        var current_item = $('.mejs-list li:first'); // get :first if we don't have .current class
        var audio_src = $(current_item).next().text();
        $(current_item).next().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
        console.log('elseif '+audio_src);
    }

    if( $(current_item).is(':last-child') ) { // if it is last - stop playing
        $(current_item).removeClass('current');
    }else{
        currentPlayer.setSrc(audio_src);
        currentPlayer.play();
    }
}
</script>
```

If there's a better way to do it using jQuery and mediaelement.js I'm open to suggestions.

p.s.
Would also be a plus if I could have previous and next track links, but it's not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out and posting answer for everyone's benefit.

HTML

```
<audio id="mejs" src="track1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls></audio>
<ul class="mejs-list">
  <li id="track1.mp3">Track1</li>
  <li id="track2.mp3">Track2</li>
  <li id="track3.mp3">Track3</li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
                success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                    mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
                        mejsPlayNext(e.target);
                    }, false);
                },
                keyActions: []
            });

            $('.mejs-list li').click(function() {
                $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
                var audio_src = this.id;
                $('audio#mejs:first').each(function(){
                    this.player.pause();
                    this.player.setSrc(audio_src);
                    this.player.play();
                });
            });

        });

        function mejsPlayNext(currentPlayer) {
            if ($('.mejs-list li.current').length > 0){ // get the .current song
                var current_item = $('.mejs-list li.current:first'); // :first is added if we have few .current classes
                var audio_src = $(current_item).next().text();
                $(current_item).next().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
                console.log('if '+audio_src);
            }else{ // if there is no .current class
                var current_item = $('.mejs-list li:first'); // get :first if we don't have .current class
                var audio_src = $(current_item).next().text();
                $(current_item).next().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
                console.log('elseif '+audio_src);
            }

            if( $(current_item).is(':last-child') ) { // if it is last - stop playing
                $(current_item).removeClass('current');
            }else{
                currentPlayer.setSrc(audio_src.match('http.*\.mp3'));
                currentPlayer.play();
            }
        }
        </script>
```

NOTE: this dose not validate HTML standerds(WC3), but it dose work, Tested
Chrome, Safari, Firefox on mac, latest versions
Still looking for HTML compliant version to validate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
 $(current_item).next().attr('id');
```

in the mejsPlayNext function.

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
        $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
            success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
                    mejsPlayNext(e.target);
                }, false);
            },
            keyActions: []
        });

        $('.mejs-list li').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
            var audio_src = this.id;
            $('audio#mejs:first').each(function(){
                this.player.pause();
                this.player.setSrc(audio_src);
                this.player.play();
            });
        });

    });

    function mejsPlayNext(currentPlayer) {
        if ($('.mejs-list li.current').length > 0){ // get the .current song
            var current_item = $('.mejs-list li.current:first'); // :first is added if we have few .current classes
            var audio_src = $(current_item).next().attr('id');
            $(current_item).next().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
            console.log('if '+audio_src);
        }else{ // if there is no .current class
            var current_item = $('.mejs-list li:first'); // get :first if we don't have .current class
            var audio_src = $(current_item).next().attr('id');
            $(current_item).next().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
            console.log('elseif '+audio_src);
        }

        if( $(current_item).is(':last-child') ) { // if it is last - stop playing
            $(current_item).removeClass('current');
        }else{
            currentPlayer.setSrc(audio_src.match('http.*\.mp3'));
            currentPlayer.play();
        }
    }
    </script>
```